# Access and modify a specific field in a web page with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am exploring the world of `javascript` in `Node.js` and have one question.

Here is the code I am referring to, the file is called *hw.js*:

```
const http = require('http'),
      hostname = '127.0.0.1',
      port = 3000;


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  let quote ="Injustice anywhere is a threat to justice everywhere.",
      counterVal = 1,
      htmlStr = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head>\n';

  htmlStr += '<title>Time-Tic</title>\n'
  htmlStr += '</head><body>\n'
  htmlStr += "<font color='brown'>" + quote + "</font><br/>\n"
  htmlStr += "<br/><b><p id='display'></p></b>\n"
  htmlStr += '</body>\n</html>'

  const SECS = 5 * 1000,
  notificationLoop = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('-- setInterval --' + counterVal + ' -- ' + Date());
    if (counterVal>65536) {clearInterval(notificationLoop);}
    counterVal *= 2
  }, SECS);

  res.end(htmlStr);
});


server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

When I load it in my browser I can see the following result in the console:

```
XYZ$ node hw.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
-- setInterval --1 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:02 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --2 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --4 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --8 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:17 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --16 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:22 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --32 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --64 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --128 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:37 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --256 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --512 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:47 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --1024 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --2048 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:31:57 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --4096 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:32:02 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --8192 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:32:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --16384 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:32:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --32768 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:32:17 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --65536 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:32:22 GMT+0200 (CEST)
-- setInterval --131072 -- Sun Jul 01 2018 19:32:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

This is what I expect. But I want to change the code so that the date appears on the web page (in the browser), in the field with id *'display'*.

How should I modifiy the code in *hw.js* to get this result?
At this point, all I have tried (at least ten ways) failed.

Comment: You need to run Javascript code in the browser, not the server.

Comment: I understand but .. In other words, what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Write a `<script>` tag in your HTML.  It will help to put the HTML in a separate file.

Comment: Try to change `htmlStr += "<br/><b><p id='display'></p></b>\n"` with `htmlStr += \`<br/><b><p id='display'>${Date()}</p></b>\n\``. Is that what you want?

Comment: I can try, but I think if I do that, I will not get the update every five seconds that I want.

Comment: @SLaks: At this point I have only one .js file and I would like to do what I want just by fixing it it is possible.